# Get Data from a Table in Spring JPA @ManyToMany relation cause StackOverFlow

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

i'm creating an example of @ManyToMany in Spring JPA with the with two Entities **Category** and **Product** and the entities as the following

## Product.java

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.Hibernate;


@Table(name = "Product")
@Entity(name = "Product")
@Builder
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column
    private double price;

    @Column
    private Integer quantity;
    
    
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "product_category",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    )
    private Set<Category> categories;

    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
        Product product = (Product) o;
        return id != null && Objects.equals(id, product.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
}
```

## Category.java

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.Hibernate;

@Table(name = "Category")
@Entity(name = "Category")
@Builder
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories" , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Product> products;
    
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
        Category category = (Category) o;
        return id != null && Objects.equals(id, category.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
}
```

when i try to use `findAll()` to get all categories from `CategoryRepo` it gives me `StackOverFlow` exception

```
at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4216) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:296) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) ~[na:na]
at com.app.ecommerce.entity.Category.toString(Category.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4216) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:296) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) ~[na:na]
at com.app.ecommerce.entity.Product.toString(Product.java:63) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4216) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:296) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) ~[na:na]
at com.app.ecommerce.entity.Category.toString(Category.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4216) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:296) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) ~[na:na]
at com.app.ecommerce.entity.Product.toString(Product.java:63) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4216) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:296) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) ~[na:na]
at com.app.ecommerce.entity.Category.toString(Category.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4216) ~[na:na]
```

and i also tried to use `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonIgnorePropertie` but it doesn't work

i would like to return all categories as the following

```
[
    {
       "id" : 1,
       "name" : "Mobile"
    }
]
```

Comment: It would be nice to get the stacktrace but I guess it is coming from the toString method. You need to implement it without using the object on both side of the relation or it will bounce between the 2

Comment: i tried to delete @ToString from the 2 classes and implement it myself and I still getting the same StackOverFlow exception

Comment: Don't use lombok on entities, that is a bad idea. Especially things like `toString`, `hashCode` and `equals`. The to string will always include all fields (the same for equals/hashCode as well) which is bad, especially with bi-directional dependencies, which will go on and on and on and on. So if you need anything implement a toString yourself, without the collections, if you are directly exposing your entities as JSON you will run into the same issue as well and this will require additional mapping information for your JSON framework.

Comment: As I said, you need to implement toString yourself and use the ID or nothing for the mapping to the other entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinite recursion is between the `toString` methods of `Product` and `Category`. At least in one exclude the other, by

- removing the `@ToString` annotation
- using [`@ToString.Exclude`](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString)
- hand code the `toString` methods.